# Angular trigger 'click' is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So the problem is next. I get a pure link from services, by click on this link user can download any file directly from amazon s3 bucket. I cannot use ajax because it will be CROS domain request, so I'm trying to simulate click on dynamic link. The function works fine but downloading doesn't begin. Where is my problem or what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
  function triggerClick() {
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log($scope.theLink); // returns link
            console.log(angular.element('#download')); // returns element
            angular.element('#download').triggerHandler('click'); // returns nothing
        }, 0);
    };

    $scope.download = function (obj) {
        downloadServices.attachment(obj)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.theLink = response.url;
                triggerClick()
            })
    }
```

html

```
  <a id="download" ng-click="triggerClick(); $event.stopPropagation();" ng-href="{{theLink}}" ng-hide="true">
   Download
</a>
```

html for download function

```
 <div ng-repeat="att in attachments">
    <div class="attach" ng-click="download(att)">
        <span>{{att.displayFilename}}</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry .. but where are you calling the download(obj) function?

Comment: Have you tried just `.trigger('click');` rather than `triggerHandler`?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi see my updated answer

Comment: @Ankh I have tried any of this way, result is the same

Comment: i think you want `ng-attr-href="{{theLink}}"` and not `ng-href` in this case

Comment: @WilliamB sorry but result hasn't changed..

Comment: `ng-click` is not a traditional click handler.  you can't trigger it from a function like that, and this doesn't really make sense anyway, since you appear to be trying to "click" the same link that called the function, meaning it would just call the function recursively.  It's not exactly clear what you are *really* trying to do here....

Comment: also, what does `downloadServices.attachment()` actually do?  you don't actually get the URL until the point that the user clicks the link?  This seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

```
 function triggerClick() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById('download').click();
            })
        }, 0);
    }

    $scope.download = function (obj) {
        lovServices.attachment(obj)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.theLink = response.url;
                triggerClick()
            })
    }
```

html

```
<div >
    <div ng-repeat="att in attachments">
        <div class="attach" ng-click="download(att)">
            <span>{{att.displayFilename}}</span><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="download" ng-href="{{theLink}}" ng-hide="true" download>
       Download
    </a>
</div>
```